# Getting Imap_listmailbox correctly but ends with PHP Notice

Tags: php, email, imap, notice

I want to scan my IMAP Mailbox on a hosteurope Mailserver for mails with PHP Imap functions. Here is my "testing" code:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{wp159.webpack.hosteurope.de:143/imap/tls/readonly}INBOX.Testingbox", "myUsername", "myPassword", NULL, 1);
if( $mbox == false )
{
  $list = 'Fehler beim Öffnen der Verbindung'; 
}
else
{
  $folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{wp159.webpack.hosteurope.de:143}INBOX.Testingbox", "*");
  if( $folders == false )
  {
    $list = "Abruf fehlgeschlagen";
  }
  else
  {
    foreach($folders as $val)
    {
      $list .= $val . " ";
    }
  }

  //$headers = imap_headers($mbox);
  if( $headers == false )
  {
    $list2 = 'Abruf fehlgeschlagen!';
  }
  else
  {
    $list2 = var_dump($headers);
  }

  imap_close($mbox);    
}
```

With this code (its nearly the same as on php.net) I get the headers and a list of mails but at the end a Notice from PHP with this text:

```
Notice: Unknown: Connection failed to wp159.webpack.hosteurope.de,143: No route to host (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
```

I could not find anything helpful with Google or here in Stackoverflow.

Why do I get this notice? As I said in $list and $list2 there is useful data but always with this Notice at the end.

Comment: I could get rid of this error when i moved the php - script, which is trying to connect to the imap account, on the same server as the imap server is...